# Add search functionality to custom list view

Tags: android, listview, search

I create custom `listView` for contacts and `EditText` for search contents.
Here is search code.

**Main Activity**

```
    EditText contactSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactSearch);
        contactSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                contentAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

`contentAdapter` is static variable which is define in another class which is in different file this class is extend from  `AysnTask`

**BackgroundWorker**

```
 public static ContentAdapter contentAdapter;
 // other code
 contentAdapter = new ContentAdapter(context, names, phones);
            listView.setAdapter(contentAdapter);
```

I make it static variable because I want to access it from mainActivity class as define above.
There is no error But search functionality does not work properly. I try to search contact but it can't search. I don't know what the problem is. There is no error but searching is not working fine.

**UPDATE** **ContentAdapter Class**

```
public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Context context;
private String[] names;
private String[] phones;
public static Dialog dialog;

ContentAdapter(Context ctx, String[] name, String[] phone){
    super(ctx, R.layout.contact_row,R.id.txtName,name);
    context = ctx;
    names = name;
    phones = phone;
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView name, phone;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNumber);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();
                String userName = name.getText().toString();
                //final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle(userName);
                EditText etxtContactNumber = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
                etxtContactNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.name.setText(names[position]);
    viewHolder.phone.setText(phones[position]);

    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: Make search function in your adapter class.

Comment: Why this code is not working any reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in adapter.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        names.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            names.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (Names wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    names.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: But how can I access the editText in adpter class because editText is in mainactivity

Comment: contentAdapter.filter(s); add this code inside onTextChanged

Comment: @JoyHelina This code is not working alot of method which is not resolve. I update the question please check it

Comment: @Pak Developer Please refer this link http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/